# How to iterate over a Map to obtain a String of repeated Character Keys with Java 8

Tags: java, string, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Map` shown below:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    map.put('c', 5);
    map.put('f', 2);
    map.put('r', 1);
    map.put('D', 3);
```

I need to obtain the *output:*

```
cccccffrDDD
```

I can do it in normal process, but I want to do it in Java 8. Can you share some hints how to achieve this?

Comment: I would use a stream operation with `Collectors.joining()` like this: `map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey().toString().repeat(e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining())` (gives `cccccffrDDD`). The `repeat` method is there since Java 11, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of ideas on how to approach this problem using *Java 8* streams.

*The overall idea:*

- create a stream of map entries;
- generate a stream of single-letter strings based on each entry and merge them using built-in collector `joining()`;
- apply collect with collector `joining()` to obtain the final result.

```
String joinedLetters = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> Stream.generate(() -> String.valueOf(entry.getKey()))
        .limit(entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

*Another way of achieving this:*

- create a stream of entries;
- create a lightweight list of Strings using `Collections.nCopies()`;
- turn each list into a `String` using static method `String.join()`;
- combine the strings together using collector `joining()`.

```
String joinedLetters = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> Collections.nCopies(entry.getValue(), String.valueOf(entry.getKey())))
    .map(list -> String.join("", list))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

*Use this link to play around with* [*Online demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/r0I)

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you need?

```java
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
        map.put('c',5);
        map.put('f', 2);
        map.put('r', 1);
        map.put('D', 3);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        map.forEach((k,v)->{
            sb.append(String.valueOf(k).repeat(v));
        });
        System.out.print(sb);
```

Notice that the repeat method is only avaliable above Java 11.

For Java 1.8 version

```java
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        map.forEach((k,v)->{
            for(int i=0; i<v; i++) {
                sb.append(k);
            }
        });
        System.out.print(sb);
```

Comment: Nice combination of the two answers posted before ;-) I admit, this fact makes your answer the best ^^

Comment: repeat was not in JAVA 8, i need it in JAVA 8 solution

Comment: We acheived the output but its not a pure function, because its modyfying the global object.

Comment: @user3309305 Thanks for the tips, I have already modified the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use forEach() and StringBuilder to compose.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
  map.forEach((k,v) -> { 
  for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) { 
    sb.append(k); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stream the entry set of the map and print the key with its value as factor using [`String.repeat(int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) (introduced in Java 11), maybe as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    map.put('c',5);
    map.put('f', 2);
    map.put('r', 1);
    map.put('D', 3);
    // stream the set of entries and repeat the (String version of the) key value-times
    map.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.print(e.getKey().toString().repeat(e.getValue())));
}
```

This prints

```
cccccffrDDD
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Java 8, which doesn’t have the `String.repeat(…)` method, you may use

```java
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e -> {
       char[] array = new char[e.getValue()];
       Arrays.fill(array, e.getKey());
       return CharBuffer.wrap(array);
   })
   .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

or use a custom collector:

```java
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        StringBuilder::new,
        (sb, e) -> { for(int i = e.getValue(); i > 0; i--) sb.append(e.getKey()); },
        StringBuilder::append,
        StringBuilder::toString));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can build the string by using the lambda expression as follows.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        output.append(k);
    }
});
```

Or you can replace the standard with IntStreams.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
map.forEach((k, v) -> IntStream.range(0, v).forEach(i -> b.append(k)));
```